# Invalid argument supplied for foreach(),no proper solution found

Tags: php

I am trying to send checkbox values using ajax jquery to other php page
i tried to check if i am getting the value using alert and i got what i wanted, but on passing it to other page using "data:" i am getting error on the other page where i am using that passed checkbox (array) to save in database.
Error is

> " : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 10

second page code :

```
> <?php
> 
> include_once('connect.php');
> 
> $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
> 
> $query="INSERT INTO `students`(`studentid`, `name`, `doa`,
> `contactno`, `contactno2`, `mailid`,
> `profession`,`reference`,`fprof`,`mprof`,`address`) VALUES
> ('','".$name."','".$_REQUEST['doa']."','".$_REQUEST['contact1']."','".$_REQUEST['contact2']."','".$_REQUEST['email']."','".$_REQUEST['prof']."','".$_REQUEST['ref']."','".$_REQUEST['fprof']."','".$_REQUEST['mprof']."','".$_REQUEST['add']."')";
> 
> mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
> 
> $last_id=mysqli_insert_id($conn);
> 
> $select=array();
> 
> $select=$_REQUEST['course'];
> 
> foreach($select as $value)    
> {         
> $query2="insert into class(studentid,courseid) values(".$last_id.",".$value.")";
> $q=mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die(mysqli_error());    
> } 
> ?>
```

**foreach($select as $value)
 is the error here**

Comment: $select=$_REQUEST['course']; // $select maybe is a String, is not array.

Comment: change $select=$_REQUEST['course']; to $select[]=$_REQUEST['course'];

Comment: perfect @kerv ! It's done

Comment: @AmItPagarIa np! Please upvote :)